# How to get the path of a file stored in Bluemix

Tags: java, path, server, websphere, ibm-cloud

I've made a project that uploads a .sql file to Bluemix using the following code:

```
Part part = request.getPart("file"); 
    String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
part.write(File.separator + fileName);
```

When I search for it in the files section of Bluemix, it shows this location: app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/64/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/myapp/myapp/db_peru.sql

Now I'm trying to get the location of the uploaded sql file (db_peru.sql) in Bluemix to run it with ScriptRunner in a ClearDB attached to the project with the following code:

```
String script="app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/64/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/myapp/myapp/db_peru.sql";

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    new ScriptRunner(DriverManager.getConnection(url)).runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(script)));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

However in log files it throws this error:

```
2016-07-13T16:28:05.961-0500[App/0]ERR[err] java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/console.ng.bluemix.net/rest/v2/apps/0a5e26ae-8c32-4333-b2a2-a1f0d403ab24/instances/0/files/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/64/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/myapp/myapp/db_peru.sql (No such file or directory)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is this just a typo in the question or in your code? "https:/console..." should be "https://console..."

Comment: Can you try this path: 
String script="workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/64/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/myapp/myapp/db_peru.sql";

Comment: data_henrik, @AndrewLohr Thank you for your replies. I tried your suggestions but the result was the same, it throws (No such file or directory). Any other idea?